# Possible reasons for adding second data source to existing application

Tags: .net, mongodb, web-applications, ravendb, nosql

So I have been looking into NoSQL databases and I have. ecome quite fascinated with them. So my question is what are some legitimate uses and/or reasons for possibly adding a second NoSql datasource to an existing n-tier enterprise web application that already makes use of a relational database?

I read on the RavenDB blog that one of the shortcomings to their database is reporting. Is this generally the case for document databases? Could you possibly some how make use of SQLServer for reporting and NoSql for other things? What might an architecture like this look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is lacking in you application, I can think of these reasons of adding a no-sql db:

- If your web application is a high traffic app then you'd like to log
  some of the user behaviour data: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/LoggingToCassandra
- Caching or in-memory use, you can always add an in-memory db like Redis, Riak, Hazelcast etc to your application to increase its performance, (can also consider memcached). This can help in search, user session and serving static content.
- If you need a pub/sub server, Redis does a good job http://redis.io/topics/pubsub
- For storing data in a structured way e.g. in JSON format or in graphs, like mongoDB, OrientDB, neo4j and CouchDBs do. You can use in-built REST apis of couchDB for directly accessing the data from a web client.
- For adding a new functionality to your web app without affecting the existing DB e.g. you wand to expose your data to the public through APIs or you want to a add real time search and index capabilities.
- For scalability, arguably no-sql dbs tend to scale better than the relational ones.

Answer (score 2):

So many good examples here.  One thing that seems to not be mentioned is creating a denormalized high transaction read layer. This is fitting in a CQRS world.  Where your data in the relational model is hard to query against to create reporting consumable data.  You could instead translate the relational model to a flat model...something document dbs do well.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is a common usage. See this other question for example:

[What's a suitable storage RDBMS,NoSQL, for caching web site responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172108/whats-a-suitable-storage-rdbms-nosql-for-caching-web-site-responses)

Comment: Wow caching. That sounds like a great idea. Have you done something like this before? Whats types web site responses are most suitable for this?

Answer (score 1):

Caching is indeed a common usage. Couchbase and Redis usually satisfy this.

Structured log storage is also a common use. People seem to like using Mongo to store structured logs (not just one flat string).

Anything dealing with a very large amount of data. For example, maybe you put a tracking pixel on your website to track page hits/views/user activity. The data generated would potentially be very large. NoSQL databases usually scale horizontally really well.

I would also argue the document databases (CouchDB, MongoDB, Couchbase) allow you to store anything that is just too painful to normalize. Spending all your time making tables and CRUD stored procedures? Might be easier to just serialize your rich objects to JSON and store that!

It's not really under NoSQL, but graph databases can efficiently store relationships between things. Think Facebook's social graph, or even a recommendation engine.

Comment: I feel like a bit of a ding dong. I have bever considered making use of a caching system. Do you know any good links or write ups on the use of caching in an eterprise type of web application?

Comment: Read about Varnish. Super fast for a specific type of caching. https://www.varnish-cache.org/. Also check out Redis. It has a ton of momentum right now. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/Iqrm5E87o9Y